# Json Creation Issue in C#

Tags: c#, json

In the below code i want to get Json format using C#. I tried the below code i don't know how to set jsonformat .SO kindly help me to resolve this issue.

I have tried the below C# Code i can't able to get exact format.So Kindly help me to resolve.

Exact Json:

```
{
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Quarterly Sales vs. Profit % in Last Year",
        "subcaption": "Product-wise Break-up - Harry's SuperMart",
        "xAxisName": "Quarter",
        "pYAxisName": "Sales",
        "sYAxisName": "Profit %",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "numbersuffix": "M",
        "sNumberSuffix": "%",
        "sYAxisMaxValue": "25",
        "paletteColors": "#5598c3,#2785c3,#31cc77,#1aaf5d,#f45b00",
        "baseFontColor": "#333333",
        "baseFont": "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
        "captionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
        "showBorder": "0",
        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
        "showShadow": "0",
        "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff",
        "canvasBorderAlpha": "0",
        "divlineAlpha": "100",
        "divlineColor": "#999999",
        "divlineThickness": "1",
        "divLineDashed": "1",
        "divLineDashLen": "1",
        "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
        "showplotborder": "0",
        "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
        "placeValuesInside": "1",
        "showXAxisLine": "1",
        "xAxisLineThickness": "1",
        "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
        "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
        "legendBgAlpha": "0",
        "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
        "legendShadow": "0",
        "legendItemFontSize": "10",
        "legendItemFontColor": "#666666"
    },
    "categories": [
        {
            "category": [
                {
                    "label": "Q1"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Q2"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Q3"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Q4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dataset": [
        {
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "seriesname": "Processed Food",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "33"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "31"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "seriesname": "Un-Processed Food",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "39"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "41"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "seriesname": "Electronics",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "25"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "26"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "seriesname": "Apparels",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "15"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "16"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "lineset": [
        {
            "seriesname": "Profit %",
            "showValues": "0",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "14"
                },
                {
                    "value": "16"
                },
                {
                    "value": "15"
                },
                {
                    "value": "17"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

C#:

```
public class Chart
{
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public string subcaption { get; set; }
    public string xAxisName { get; set; }
    public string pYAxisName { get; set; }
    public string sYAxisName { get; set; }
    public string numberPrefix { get; set; }
    public string numbersuffix { get; set; }
    public string sNumberSuffix { get; set; }
    public string sYAxisMaxValue { get; set; }
    public string paletteColors { get; set; }
    public string baseFontColor { get; set; }
    public string baseFont { get; set; }
    public string captionFontSize { get; set; }
    public string subcaptionFontSize { get; set; }
    public string subcaptionFontBold { get; set; }
    public string showBorder { get; set; }
    public string bgColor { get; set; }
    public string showShadow { get; set; }
    public string canvasBgColor { get; set; }
    public string canvasBorderAlpha { get; set; }
    public string divlineAlpha { get; set; }
    public string divlineColor { get; set; }
    public string divlineThickness { get; set; }
    public string divLineDashed { get; set; }
    public string divLineDashLen { get; set; }
    public string usePlotGradientColor { get; set; }
    public string showplotborder { get; set; }
    public string valueFontColor { get; set; }
    public string placeValuesInside { get; set; }
    public string showXAxisLine { get; set; }
    public string xAxisLineThickness { get; set; }
    public string xAxisLineColor { get; set; }
    public string showAlternateHGridColor { get; set; }
    public string legendBgAlpha { get; set; }
    public string legendBorderAlpha { get; set; }
    public string legendShadow { get; set; }
    public string legendItemFontSize { get; set; }
    public string legendItemFontColor { get; set; }
}

public class Category2
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public List<Category2> category { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Dataset2
{
    public string seriesname { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class Dataset
{
    public List<Dataset2> dataset { get; set; }
}

public class Datum2
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Lineset
{
    public string seriesname { get; set; }
    public string showValues { get; set; }
    public List<Datum2> data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Chart chart { get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public List<Dataset> dataset { get; set; }
    public List<Lineset> lineset { get; set; }
}


public Chart DD()
{
    Chart NewChart = new Chart();
    NewChart.caption = "";
    NewChart.subcaption = "";
    NewChart.xAxisName = "";
    NewChart.pYAxisName = "";
    NewChart.sYAxisName = "";
    NewChart.numberPrefix = "";
    NewChart.numbersuffix = "";
    NewChart.sNumberSuffix = "";
    NewChart.sYAxisMaxValue = "";
    NewChart.paletteColors = "";
    NewChart.baseFontColor = "";
    NewChart.baseFont = "";
    NewChart.captionFontSize = "";
    NewChart.subcaptionFontSize = "";
    NewChart.subcaptionFontBold = "";
    NewChart.showBorder = "";
    NewChart.bgColor = "";
    NewChart.showShadow = "";
    NewChart.canvasBgColor = "";
    NewChart.canvasBorderAlpha = "";
    NewChart.divlineAlpha = "";
    NewChart.divlineColor = "";
    NewChart.divlineThickness = "";
    NewChart.divLineDashed = "";
    NewChart.divLineDashLen = "";
    NewChart.usePlotGradientColor = "";
    NewChart.showplotborder = "";
    NewChart.valueFontColor = "";
    NewChart.placeValuesInside = "";
    NewChart.showXAxisLine = "";
    NewChart.xAxisLineThickness = "";
    NewChart.xAxisLineColor = "";
    NewChart.showAlternateHGridColor = "";
    NewChart.legendBgAlpha = "";
    NewChart.legendBorderAlpha = "";
    NewChart.legendShadow = "";
    NewChart.legendItemFontSize = "";
    NewChart.legendItemFontColor = "";




    return NewChart;
}
```

Comment: Try using https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json to simplify JSON operations with C#

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What is the issue? What part is not working? Did it thorw exception? If yes What was the exception? Include full details with the question and people will help you out find the solution of this problem.